# How to write into input stream in java

Tags: java, windows

Suppose i execute a command in java using the exec() function and i store the reference in a Process . How do i write into the input stream of that process

```
Process P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start telnet"); 
System.out.println("done running .."); 
OutputStream output = P.getOutputStream(); 
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(output); 
String S = "open\n"; 
byte[] BS = S.getBytes(); 
out.write(BS); out.close();
```

I had done that but its not workin.......... above is my code attached

Answer (score 2):

You write to the output stream not the input stream:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..);
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
bos.write("whatever u want");
```

Comment: Process P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start telnet"); System.out.println("done running .."); OutputStream output = P.getOutputStream(); BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(output); String S = "open\n"; byte[] BS = S.getBytes(); out.write(BS); out.close(); 
I had done that but its not workin above is my code attache

Comment: Did you try with BufferedWriter

Comment: Maybe if starting from Windows and sending the command to UNix, the \n after open may create some problem

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you actually want the Process' OutputStream, because you want to send data to the process (unless I misunderstood your question).

[Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/ProcessgetOutputStream.htm).

Comment: Its possible he wants to write to the input stream to simulate user input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `cmd /c` bit in your `exec` call. Since exec itself will spawn a shell for you. Regardless, process handling in Java is a real pain. If you can I suggest you use the [Apache exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) package. It handles a lot of the low level pain for you.